# Kotlin generic class with embedded instance of parameter

Tags: kotlin, generics

```
class ZabbixAPIResult<T> {
    var jsonrpc = ""
    var result = T()
    var id = ""
}
```

yields

```
type parameter T cannot be called as a function
```

Is it possible to declare something like this in Kotlin?  I.e., a class that embeds an instance of a class supplied as a parameter?

Comment: No you can't. 1. This is not the syntax to define a variable. 2. Kotlin knows nothing about what that T is, it can't create it's object like this.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can have a field with type `T`. But you need to pass either the instance itself or a way to construct it. E.g.

```
class ZabbixAPIResult<T>(var result: T) {
    var jsonrpc = ""
    var id = ""
}
```

or

```
class ZabbixAPIResult<T>(resultFun: () => T) {
    var jsonrpc = ""
    var result = resultFun()
    var id = ""
}
```

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors for the details of this syntax.

But Kotlin can't assume `T` is a class with a default constructor, so your version doesn't work.

(On a side note, it's generally better to avoid using `var` by default.)

Comment: Thanks;  in this situation I had to use `var` to satisfy the deserialisation package I was using.